# Advance resampling using Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have 1 minute interval data. I would like to resample into two frequency one at 30min(Coarse resolution) and other at 5min(fine resolution) for the same series. There is a condition for having coarse and fine resolution data, if data crosses a threshold (-22 in this example), it should be resampled at 5 min otherwise it should be resampled at 30 minutes. I have one example data set below :

In this case my threshold value is -22, if values is less than -22, then resample at fine resolution (5min) otherwise resample at coarse resolution(30min)

```
2018-03-20 08:02:00   -21.344299
2018-03-20 08:03:00   -21.303697
2018-03-20 08:04:00   -21.245916
2018-03-20 08:05:00   -21.328162
2018-03-20 08:06:00   -21.296409
2018-03-20 08:07:00   -21.318793
2018-03-20 08:08:00   -21.259450
2018-03-20 08:09:00   -21.346382
2018-03-20 08:10:00   -21.424463
2018-03-20 08:11:00   -21.466628
2018-03-20 08:12:00   -21.408326
2018-03-20 08:13:00   -21.346902
2018-03-20 08:14:00   -21.374491
2018-03-20 08:15:00   -21.536902
2018-03-20 08:16:00   -21.638408
2018-03-20 08:17:00   -21.547834
2018-03-20 08:18:00   -21.606655
2018-03-20 08:19:00   -21.674846
2018-03-20 08:20:00   -21.728983
2018-03-20 08:21:00   -22.026737
2018-03-20 08:22:00   -21.530134
2018-03-20 08:23:00   -21.430710
2018-03-20 08:24:00   -21.530134
2018-03-20 08:25:00   -21.471833
2018-03-20 08:26:00   -21.473395
2018-03-20 08:27:00   -21.505669
2018-03-20 08:28:00   -21.530655
2018-03-20 08:29:00   -21.654545
2018-03-20 08:30:00   -21.902847
2018-03-20 08:31:00   -21.411970
                         ...    
2018-03-24 13:33:00   -22.319808
2018-03-24 13:34:00   -22.272957
2018-03-24 13:35:00   -22.338546
2018-03-24 13:36:00   -22.242244
2018-03-24 13:37:00   -22.299506
2018-03-24 13:38:00   -22.181342
2018-03-24 13:39:00   -22.219341
2018-03-24 13:40:00   -22.281286
2018-03-24 13:41:00   -22.399453
2018-03-24 13:42:00   -22.049120
2018-03-24 13:43:00   -22.283889
2018-03-24 13:44:00   -22.187066
2018-03-24 13:45:00   -22.335423
2018-03-24 13:46:00   -22.140218
2018-03-24 13:47:00   -21.938244
2018-03-24 13:48:00   -22.055889
2018-03-24 13:49:00   -22.297942
2018-03-24 13:50:00   -22.189148
2018-03-24 13:51:00   -21.996024
2018-03-24 13:52:00   -21.985094
2018-03-24 13:53:00   -21.996544
2018-03-24 13:54:00   -21.933560
2018-03-24 13:55:00   -21.933558
2018-03-24 13:56:00   -22.435889
2018-03-24 13:57:00   -22.093367
2018-03-24 13:58:00   -22.051723
2018-03-24 13:59:00   -22.291698
2018-03-24 14:00:00   -22.351040
2018-03-24 14:01:00   -22.006435
2018-03-24 14:02:00   -22.007475
```

In this case, I expect ans like this :

```
2018-03-20 08:02:00   -21.4889   (This is mean over 30 min)
2018-03-24 13:33:00   -22.2946   (This is mean over 5 min)
2018-03-24 13:38:00   -22.2261
2018-03-24 13:43:00   -22.177
```

Is there any builtin feature for this problem ?

Comment: This is very confusing. Please take the time to show what you mean. Read [mcve]

Comment: Thanks for your comment @piRSquared. Is it clear now ?  I have edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
df = df.set_index(0)

g = df[1].lt(-22).mul(1).diff().bfill().ne(0).cumsum()

df.groupby(g).apply(lambda x: x.resample('5T', kind='period').mean().reset_index()
                           if (x.iloc[0] < -22).any() else 
                              x.resample('30T', kind='period').mean().reset_index())\
   .reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
                  0          1
0  2018-03-20 08:02 -21.431450
1  2018-03-20 08:21 -22.026737
2  2018-03-20 08:22 -21.544189
3  2018-03-24 13:33 -22.294612
4  2018-03-24 13:38 -22.226108
5  2018-03-24 13:43 -22.236649
6  2018-03-24 13:47 -21.938244
7  2018-03-24 13:48 -22.180993
8  2018-03-24 13:51 -21.968956
9  2018-03-24 13:56 -22.244743
10 2018-03-24 14:01 -22.006955
```

Comment: Thanks @Scott Boston, I didn't understand the use of df = df.set_index(0)

g = df[1].lt(-22).mul(1).diff().bfill().ne(0).cumsum()

Comment: Well, first off I am moving that datetime field in to the index, if df[0], the first column of the dataframe since there were no column names, is not datetime dtype, then you need to use pd.to_datetime to create a DatetimeIndex for the dataframe.   Next, I create groups, g, by checking first if each value in df[1] is less than -22.0, your threshold.  Then, we convert that boolean to interger with mul(1) and take the difference, if the difference is not equal to zero, we use cumsum to increment by one.   This creates groups in your dataframe.  Now, we can resample those grouped records.

Comment: Thanks clear now, just a quick query. Is there a way to implement more than one threshold in this same code. If I have an array of threshold is it possible to implement ?

Comment: Yes, I believe it is all on how you chop of your dataframe in to groups.  In this code , we are using .lt(-22) for true or false, I think you can add to that condition to create new groups with other thresholds.